# MySQL exclude records(rows) where it matches joined table

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I would like to exclude records from my query result where Table1 ID equals Table2's table1_id, which sounds easy enough, but in my original query I have multiple left joined tables and I couldn't figure out how to factor in the new table.

lets say the table1(aka product) and table2 looks like this (i won't post the other tables because i think they are irrelevant in this case):

```
table1(product)                            table2
-----------------                          ---------------------------
id | sale | price | tax | active | m_id    id | table1_id | feature_id
1  | 1    | 100   | 1   | 1      | 1       1  | 2         | 333
2  | 1    | 100   | 1   | 1      | 1       2  | 2         | 444
3  | 1    | 100   | 2   | 1      | 1       3  | 2         | 555
4  | 1    | 100   | 2   | 1      | 1       4  | 3         | 555
                                           5  | 3         | 333
```

if we look at the tables above than I need to exclude table1.id=2 and table1.id=3 because those are in table2.

My original query looks like this:

```
SELECT 
p.`id`,
0 AS `id_a`,
p.`ref` AS `Reference`,  
gy.`name` AS `MF`, 
pl.`name` AS `Full Name`,
pq.`quantity` AS `QTY`,  
IF(p.`tax`=1, ROUND(p.`price`*1.27), ROUND(p.`price`*1.18)) AS `Price`,
IF(p.`sale`=1, ROUND(sp.`discount`), "0") AS `discount amount`, 
CONCAT("http://example.com/",pl.`sef`,".html") AS `URL`, 
IF(pi.`id` IS NOT NULL, CONCAT( 'http://example.com/image/', pi.`id_image`, '-default.jpg' ), 'http://example.com/image/noimage.jpg') AS `image`
FROM `product` p
LEFT JOIN `stock` pq ON (p.`id` = pq.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `product_lng` pl ON (p.`id` = pl.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `manufacturer` gy ON (p.`m_id` = gy.`m_id`)
LEFT JOIN `image` pi ON (p.`id` = pi.`id`)
LEFT JOIN `discount_price` sp ON (p.`id` = sp.`id`)
WHERE p.`active`=1 AND pl.`lang_id`=1 AND pq.`quantity` > 0 AND p.`price` > 0
GROUP BY p.`id`
ORDER BY gy.`name`, pl.`name`
```

How can I factor in table2 into the above query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `where` clause you could add:

```
and p.id not in (select table1_id from table2)
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like its working. I would never have thought about doing another `select` in `where`